# Is there a way to print base address (hex) not as characters but as readable 0x00000 format in a messagebox

Tags: c++, winapi, dll-injection

```
void PrintBaseAddr() {
    while (true) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F6) & 0x80000) {
            HMODULE BaseAddr = GetModuleHandleA(NULL);
            BaseAddr += 0x351333;


            MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)BaseAddr, "Base Address", MB_OK);
        }
    }
}
```

so this is my code and the problem is, that BaseAddr is printed like this:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJUEC.png)

how can i cast it to something like 0xABC345FF?

Comment: Hm. Can't see C++ here, only WinAPI. :-)

Comment: The problem with casting something to a string that isn't a string is it doesn't work very well. You could use something like `sprintf` to create a string from the value.

Comment: You can format it into a string. Actually, you probably _should_ format it into a string because i'm like 99% sure that the text box is expecting a `*char` as its input.

Comment: @DevSolar: Is the `#` in your `sprintf` format string a typo? Or is this a Microsoft-specific extension?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel `#` is a standard flag for `sprintf()`, but its use with `%p` is not defined by either Microsoft or the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MessageBox` expects to receive a string. Since you want to pass an address and render it as a hexadecimal number, you need to create a string holding the hexadecimal number first.

```cpp
void PrintBaseAddr() {
    while (true) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F6) & 0x80000) {
            HMODULE BaseAddr = GetModuleHandleA(NULL);
            BaseAddr += 0x351333;

            std::ostringsream buffer;
            buffer << (void *)BaseAddr;

            MessageBoxA(NULL, buffer.str().c_str(), "Base Address", MB_OK);
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using `MessageBox` quite a bit, it's sometimes useful to create a manipulator to handle this:

```cpp
class MessageBox {
    std::string title;
    int type;
public:
    MessageBox(std::string const &title, int type = MB_OK) 
        : title(title), type(type) 
    { }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, MessageBox const &m) {
        auto &oss = dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream &>(os);

        MessageBox(NULL, oss.str().c_str(), m.title, m.type);
        return os;
    }
};
```

You'd use this something like:

```cpp
std::ostringstream os;
os << (void *)BaseAddress << MessageBox("Base Address");
```

The good point here is that you get all the usual stream capabilities, so if you need to print out some random class you can't deal with directly (but provides an overloaded `<<` operator) you can use it in a MessageBox.

Comment: [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) turns that into a single line of code.